# What is the time complexity of the following function, that uses buit-in sorted function?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I am preperaing for a job interview and was wondering what is the time complexity of **find_missing** function in the following code I wrote, that finds the missing value in an unsorted list of values between 1 and 99. I am rather new to complexity theory and not sure how to properly count it, when using the built-in **sorted** function.

```
def find_missing(num_array):
    num_array = sorted(num_array)
    print(num_array)
    for k in range(len(num_array)-1):
        if num_array[k] == num_array[k+1] - 1:
            continue
        else:
            return num_array[k] + 1
```

Comment: It's still O(n lg n), because that's the worst-case running time for `sorted`.  You don't need to sort, though. Take advantage of the fixed range to do something in O(n) time. (Hint: trade time for additional memory.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort algorithms are usually between `O(n log(n))` up to `O(n²)`. Built-in sort functions are usually `O(n log(n))`. Your for loop is also `O(n)` and as a result the time complexity of your algorithm is `O(n log(n)) + n)` which is `O(n log(n))`.

And because you're creating a new array in the first line, the memory complexity is `O(n)`

In addition you can use a hash table to improve both time and memory complexity.

Answer (score 6):

Python built-in sorting function is a custom sorting function called `Timsort` with a time complexity of `O(n log n)`.

More on that in Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)